# Youtube player iFrame ignores playsinline param

Tags: ios7, youtube-iframe-api

I'm embedding a youtube video with the following HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">body {background-color: transparent;color: white;}</style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0">
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?playsinline=1&rel=0&showinfo=0" width="320" height="160" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
```

But the playsinline param gets ignored. It always enters to black screen and starts showing the video controls.

What exactly should I do so it respects that value I'm passing?